# need to refer log4net config file in AssemblyInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, logging, path

I use following code for refer the App.Config File in `AssemblyInfo.cs` for create log file.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @"C:\Users\Projects\Model\App.config", Watch = true)]
```

I dont want to give Full path details in `AssemblyInfo.cs` page.Because it will change by system wise.How to refer the file without giving full path? For example using like

```
../../ or ~/
```

Comment: You have added log4net section to app.config. You don't need to add this in Assemblyinfo.cs. Just define a sectionhandler in your app.config and call the configurator in your code.

Answer (score 4):

The following code in AssemblyInfo will instruct Log4Net to configure using your App.Config:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```